# View Contents of COM DLL in .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com, com-interop

I am new to `C#` and need to utilize a `COM DLL` in my application.

I have executed `tlbimp` against the original `DLL`, registered my new `DLL` with `regsvr32`, viewed the contents of the `DLL` with `ildasm` and then recreated and signed the `DLL` using `/ilasm /res /dll /key` (using the same key as for my C# projects).
I then added the new, signed `DLL` to my `GAC`.

I added a `reference` to the `DLL` within my application and am able to output the `Type` of each `method` in the `DLL` structure.

> I am expecting this `DLL` to have an `array(s)` of values but have been unable to execute the `get` methods and do not see any arrays in the structure dump file.
>
> The two arrays I am expecting would be of type `INT` and `STRING`. This `DLL` is supposed to be able to populate a `combobox`

Below is the dump of the DLL using `ildasm`

> Can somebody please tell me if there is in fact an array of values in this `DLL` or if I should stop spinning my wheels?

```
___[MOD] 
   |      M A N I F E S T
   |___[NSP] CSCICom_Usable
   |   |___[INT] CSCICom_Usable.Class1
   |   |   |     .class interface public abstract auto ansi import 
   |   |   |      implements CSCICom_Usable._Class1 
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 24 32 34 42 33 31 37 34 37 2D 41 46 42 36   // ..$24B31747-AFB6 ...
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.CoClassAttribute::.ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Type) = ( 01 00 1A 43 53 43 49 43 6F 6D 5F 55 73 61 62 6C   // ...CSCICom_Usabl ...
   |   |
   |   |___[CLS] CSCICom_Usable.Class1Class
   |   |   |     .class public auto ansi import 
   |   |   |      implements CSCICom_Usable._Class1 
   |   |   |      implements CSCICom_Usable.Class1 
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeLibTypeAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeLibTypeFlags) = ( 01 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 )  ...
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 24 37 32 43 45 36 35 44 45 2D 46 30 42 38   // ..$72CE65DE-F0B8 ...
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterfaceAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterfaceType) = ( 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 )  ...
   |   |   |___[MET] .ctor : void()
   |   |   |___[MET] GetIncidentCodes : class [VBA]VBA.Collection()
   |   |
   |   |___[INT] CSCICom_Usable.Class2
   |   |   |     .class interface public abstract auto ansi import 
   |   |   |      implements CSCICom_Usable._Class2 
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 24 41 38 38 36 33 32 42 42 2D 41 46 46 31   // ..$A88632BB-AFF1 ...
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.CoClassAttribute::.ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Type) = ( 01 00 1A 43 53 43 49 43 6F 6D 5F 55 73 61 62 6C   // ...CSCICom_Usabl ...
   |   |
   |   |___[CLS] CSCICom_Usable.Class2Class
   |   |   |     .class public auto ansi import 
   |   |   |      implements CSCICom_Usable._Class2 
   |   |   |      implements CSCICom_Usable.Class2 
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeLibTypeAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeLibTypeFlags) = ( 01 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 )  ...
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 24 41 30 43 39 46 42 45 45 2D 42 36 45 38   // ..$A0C9FBEE-B6E8 ...
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterfaceAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterfaceType) = ( 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 )  ...
   |   |   |___[MET] .ctor : void()
   |   |   |___[MET] get_Code : int16()
   |   |   |___[MET] get_Name : string()
   |   |   |___[MET] set_Code : void(int16)
   |   |   |___[MET] set_Name : void(string)
   |   |   |___[PTY] Code : int16()
   |   |   |___[PTY] Name : string()
   |   |
   |   |___[INT] CSCICom_Usable._Class1
   |   |   |     .class interface public abstract auto ansi import 
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeLibTypeAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeLibTypeFlags) = ( 01 00 D0 10 00 00 00 00 )  ...
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 24 32 34 42 33 31 37 34 37 2D 41 46 42 36   // ..$24B31747-AFB6 ...
   |   |   |___[MET] GetIncidentCodes : class [VBA]VBA.Collection()
   |   |
   |   |___[INT] CSCICom_Usable._Class2
   |   |   |     .class interface public abstract auto ansi import 
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeLibTypeAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeLibTypeFlags) = ( 01 00 D0 10 00 00 00 00 )  ...
   |   |   |     .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 24 41 38 38 36 33 32 42 42 2D 41 46 46 31   // ..$A88632BB-AFF1 ...
   |   |   |___[MET] get_Code : int16()
   |   |   |___[MET] get_Name : string()
   |   |   |___[MET] set_Code : void(int16)
   |   |   |___[MET] set_Name : void(string)
   |   |   |___[PTY] Code : int16()
   |   |   |___[PTY] Name : string()
   |   |
   |
```

Comment: What kind of array of values are you looking for? What a value should represent?

Comment: I am expecting this application to be able to give me the values of two arrays, one which is `STRING` the other which is `INT`
Additionally I expect these two values to be tied to each other, they are Police Codes and Code Names

Comment: If you feel this deserves a downvote, please at least explain so I can improve

Comment: I suspect someone here at StackOverflow downvotes questions tagged `com`, `atl`, `activex`, etc. in a rather arbitrary way.  A common pattern seems to be questions of users with low rep, i.e. new users.

Answer (score -1):

So after moving forward with implementing my COM DLL, and substituting my own methods in the mean time. I have since been told & realized two things

1. Within the above code you can see that [MET] GetIncidentCodes returns a VBA.Collection() i.e. an array.
2. I was told that there are two items in the Collection. I am sincerely hoping that they are NOT 0 and blank..... but that is all I have been able to return so far.

Learning C# continues